# G++ equivalents for VisualC++ /vmg /vms

Tags: windows, visual-c++, g++, pointer-to-member

I want to compile a plugin for an application as a dynamic library. Usually, plugins are compiled with VisualC++, but I'd like to use G++. The SDK Documentation explicitly states

> The compiler options for Pointer-to-member representation **must** be set to "General-Purpose Always" and "Point to Single-Inheritance Classes" in C++ tab/C++ language (/vmg /vms). If not set the plugin **will** crash instantly!

And indeed, it does crash instantly as soon as I pass values from my plugin to the application. Are there any options that result in the same behaviour as `/vmg /vms` in VisualC++?

---

**Platform**: Windows 7 x64
**Compiler**: MingW32 G++ 4.6.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since pointer-to-member representation is an implementation detail, and GCC ABI is not designed to be compatible with that of MSVC, there is never going to be an equivalent.

You will not be able to mix binaries compiled with said compilers as long as the working depends on implementation-specific (unspecified) details like the pointer representations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems like I need to get into the VC++ compiler.